# How can I align the y-axes of combined graphs?

Tags: graph, stata

I am trying to combine multiple graphs in Stata using the command `graph combine`. The individual graphs are produced from the *community-contributed* command `ciplot`.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
sysuse auto 
ciplot foreign, by(rep78) hor ///
    graphregion(color(white)) ///
    rcap(lcolor(black) msiz(zero)) ///
    mc(black) ms(O) ///
    note("") xtitle( ) ///
    fysize(62.5) saving(g1, replace ) nodraw

ciplot foreign, by(headroom) hor ///
    graphregion(color(white)) ///
    rcap(lcolor(black) msiz(zero)) ///
    mc(black) ms(O) ///
    note("") xtitle( ) ///
    fysize(100) saving(g2, replace ) nodraw

gr combine g1.gph ///
    g2.gph ///
    , col(1) xcom graphregion(color(white)) ///
    title("Proportion of patients across studied variables")
```

All works as expected and I get a graph like the one below:

[image]

The problem is that the `y-axes` of the graphs start in slightly different positions, due to the different width of the labels of individual ticks. The problem gets even worse when larger discrepancies between these labels exist.

Is there a way to force the `y-axes` to start from the same point in the graph region?

Answer (score 3):

One way to improve the graph is using the `titlegap()` option. But it may not be satisfactory because manual tweaking is involved, and the result won't be perfect. Furthermore, if many graphs are being made, incorporating the change into the code might turn out to be cumbersome.

For example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

ciplot foreign, by(rep78) hor ///
    graphregion(color(white)) ///
    rcap(lcolor(black) msiz(zero)) ///
    mc(black) ms(O) ///
    note("") xtitle( ) ///
    yscale(titlegap(3.5)) ///
    fysize(62.5) saving(g1, replace ) nodraw

ciplot foreign, by(headroom) hor ///
    graphregion(color(white)) ///
    rcap(lcolor(black) msiz(zero)) ///
    mc(black) ms(O) ///
    note("") xtitle( ) ///
    fysize(100) saving(g2, replace ) nodraw

gr combine g1.gph g2.gph, ///
    col(1) xcom graphregion(color(white)) ///
    title("Proportion of patients across studied variables")
```

The `outergap()` option provides a similar solution. These options are documented in `help axis_scale_options`.

Comment: Thank you Roberto. That might work as a quick fix but as you pointed - won't satisfactorily solve the issue. Experimenting now with: 1) creating small dataset with estimates and CI using `statsby` 2)  graphing using `metan`.

Comment: @radek Roberto's solution is more than satisfactory if you do not want to have the same decimals as in my answer. Roberto's solution can also be  generalized easily so you do not have to specify yourself the number of spaces required (again based on the maximum number of decimals).

Answer (score 0):

A tick's label width in this case clearly depends on the number of decimals.

There are two main problems here:

- `ciplot` does not allow the format of variable levels to be specified in the `y-axis` label.
- `graph combine` draws again both graphs before it combines them.

Below is a a fairly general fix that standardises the decimals in the combined graph:

```
graph combine g1 g2, cols(1) ///
                     xcommon ///
                     graphregion(color(white)) ///
                     title("Proportion of patients across studied variables") ///
                     nodraw ///
                     name(g3, replace)

local decimals 1
local i 0

foreach var in rep78 headroom {
    local ++i
    local j 0
    quietly levelsof `var', local(`var'm)
    foreach l of local `var'm {
        local ++j
        local il : display %2.`decimals'f `l'
        .g3.plotregion1.graph`i'.yaxis1.major.ticks[`j'][2] = "`il'"
    }  
}

graph display g3
```

[image]

Note that you cannot use the `ylabel()` option in `ciplot` to specify the tick labels because you do not know *a priori* the actual tick values.